# Нужна функция, которая работает как калькулятор

Tags: javascript

Задача:

> Необходимо, чтобы функция решала простую математическую задачу, которая поступает в виде массива. Результат выводим в консоль.

Вот функция и примеры для реализации.
Функция принимает только 1 параметр.

```
function getResult (calculator) {
  
}

getResult(["100", "+", 200]) // 300
getResult([90, "/", 30]); // 3
getResult(["5", "-", "5"]); // 0
getResult(["7", ">", "12"]); // false
getResult(["7", "<", "12"]); // true
getResult(["2", '**', 4]); // 'Ошибка'
getResult(["*", "10", 25]); // 'Ошибка'
```

Первым делом конечно нужно привести к типу данных number либо string, тут без разницы это не сложно. А вот как дальше быть не пойму. Я такую задачу еще не решал и примера не смог найти. А сам додуматься ни как не могу.

Comment: а в чем заключается вопрос?

Comment: _number либо string, тут без разницы_ Разница есть и очень большая!

Comment: Используйте `number()`, `parseInt()` или `+` перед "числом" для преобразования строки в число. Для выбора действия вам поможет `swith()`

Comment: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. **Приведите код, который вы написали**, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: @SwaD не `number()`, а `Number()`. Не `swith()`, а `switch()`.

Comment: @ΝNL993 Да! Ну ачипятался... с кем не бывает )

Comment: @SwaD

```
function getMathResult(expression) {
  firstNumer = Number(expression[0])
  secondNumer = Number(expression[2])
  operator = String(expression[1])
  if (operator === '+') {
    return firstNumer + secondNumer
  } else if (operator === '-') {
    return firstNumber - secondNumber
  } else if (operator === '*') {
    return firstNumber * secondNumber
  } else if (operator === '/') {
    return firstNumber / secondNumber
  }
}
```
Это максимум к чему я пришел и то нашел в интернете. Я бы не писал, если бы знал как решить. Думаю это логично.

Comment: Ну вот в том, что вы приводите, нет видимых попыток разобраться. Код который вы привели будет возвращать результат, а не выводить данные в консоль, так же код сломается, если передать не число в 1-м или 3-м элементе массива. Попробуйте написать код самостоятельно, осмысливая каждую строку, что она делает и зачем. К фукнции выше осталось докрутить проверки на знаки < > и сделать проверку, что переданное значение число.

Comment: @SwaD  Вы случайно не мой куратор?)) Очень похоже высказываетесь)

Comment: Нет. Однако, если принесете код, который дан в ответе ниже, получите неуд(как минимум, если не сможете объяснить, что там происходит).

Comment: @SwaD Я учусь не для того, чтобы копипастить. У меня уже был готовый ответ от лектора. Я преследовал 2 цели посмотреть какие еще варианты решения есть. Досконально понять, разные подходы к решению и уже на этой основе решить самостоятельно. 
Просто есть очень много методов, которые каждый раз преподносят сюрпризы, что оказывается можно еще вот так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> А вот как дальше быть не пойму. Я такую задачу еще не решал и примера не смог найти.

Предложу вот такой вариант функции. Используется возможность самому "создать" тело некой функции и потом ее использовать. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function

```js
function getResult (a = []) {
  if (isNaN(a[0]) || isNaN(a[2])) return 'Ошибка'
  const op = ['+', '-', '/', '>', '<', '*', '**']
  if (op.indexOf(a[1]) == -1) return 'Ошибка'
  let v
  try {
    const tmp = new Function(`return ${+a[0]} ${a[1]} ${+a[2]}`)
    v = tmp()
  } catch(e) {
    v = 'Ошибка'
  }
  return v
}

console.log(getResult(["100", "+", 200])) // 300
console.log(getResult([90, "/", 30])); // 3
console.log(getResult(["5", "-", "5"])); // 0
console.log(getResult(["7", ">", "12"])); // false
console.log(getResult(["7", "<", "12"])); // true
console.log(getResult(["2", '**', 4])); // 16
console.log(getResult(["*", "10", 25])); // 'Ошибка'
console.log(getResult(['(function() {console.log("hello!"); return "Я подменил возвращаемое значение"})();', '+', 2]))
```

Comment: Оооо, ну ясно, вы наверное про CORS не слышали? :)

Comment: А про безопасность я вообще молчу... `getResult(['(function() {console.log("hello!"); return "Я подменил возвращаемое значение"})();', '+', 2])`

Comment: @ΝNL993, а причем тут CORS?

Comment: @Grundy достаточно строгий CORS запрещает использование `eval` и `Function` для вызова кода. Посмотрите на оригинальный ответ без изменений.

Comment: @ΝNL993, `CORS` не связан с `eval`

Comment: @Grundy перепроверил, так оно и есть.